# Do asyncio tasks share memory?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have multiple async functions in my Python application.

The functions perform actions that Read the file contents, manipulate and convert to binary

As an instance:

```
async def perform_all(location):
  file_contents = await get_file(location)
  new_file_contents = await manipulate_file(file_contents)
  in_binary = await convert_to_binary(new_file_contents)
  await save(location + '.binary', in_binary)
```

All of these individual functions are async:

```
async def get_file(location):
   # ... open file, read all and send contents

async def manipulate_file(file_contents):
   # ... do something to the contents like add their lengths together

async def convert_to_binary(new_file_contents):
   # ... given the characters, convert to binary and return it

async def save(location, in_binary):
   # ... save binary in the location
```

At the application start up, I create 5 tasks.
Each task runs the `perform_all()` function with a different location.
The function `perform_all()` is executed every 1 minute by a loop that runs within a task.
It looks for the file and converts it to binary.

I have few questions if they can be answered please:

1. Is this code asyncio-safe?
2. If not then for the sake of understanding, how do I make it non-asyncio-safe so that I can visualise the problem?
3. Can the two tasks manipulate the same file contents by mistake or each task will get its own memory allocated to it and the file contents within one task are different than the `file_contents` within another task?

Comment: The variable `file_contents` exists separately for each instance of `perform_all`. The actual *file contents* exist only once, so you have to take care that same the file is not written by multiple tasks concurrently. If `location` is different for each task, this is not a problem because they are different files.

Comment: If the file location is different then can I say that everything within perform_all will be allocated within each task's internal memory that is isolated from the other tasks' memory?